# How do I pass an list<customClass> to mvc.perform content

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mockito

I am trying to write unit tests and i am stuck at this. 
So i have a rest endpoint which takes an DTO object and the DTO is defined as below

```
public class myDTO {
    @Getter
    private String reason;
    @Getter
    private Long id;
    @Getter
    private OffsetDateTime vDate;
    @Getter
    private List<customClass> charges;
    @Getter
    private String comment;

    public AddReasonDTO(Long id, OffsetDateTime vDate, String reason, List<customClass> charges,
            String comment) {
        super();
        this.reason = reason;
        this.visitDate = visitDate;
        this.id = id;
        this.charges = charges;
        this.comment = comment;
    }
}
```

My customClass has 3 attributes

String chargeItem; float amount; int quantity;

Below is how i am trying to write my test

```
 @Test

    public void testReason() throws Exception {
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    long id = 123;
    List<customClass> cc = new ArrayList<customClass>();
    cc.add(new customClass("laptop",33.56f,4);
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
    jsonObj.put("id",id);
    jsonObj.put("charge",objectMapper.writeValueAsString(cc));
    mvc.perform(post("/addReason").content(jsonObj.toString()).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
     .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

Now the issue is i get the error **"JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList"**

I have tried using JSONArray(shown below)

```
JSONArray js = new JSONArray();
js.add(cc.get(0));
```

and then added this to JSONObject

```
jsonObj.put("charge",js)
```

But this doesn't work either.

Comment: Try make object of myDTO class and then use ObjectMapper serialize into json format string

Comment: I made the change, So now this issue is gone but i have the vDate as OffSetDateTime and that breaks now :(. Its also JSON parser error

JSON parse error: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected one of [VALUE_STRING, VALUE_NUMBER_INT, VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT] for java.time.OffsetDateTime value; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected one of [VALUE_STRING, VALUE_NUMBER_INT, VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT] for java.time.OffsetDateTime value

Comment: I use jackson library serialize you class success,can you post some code?